# Checking my question related to partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, partial-derivative

[image]

I have a question.

Is the soltion way true? If it is true, how do I show what I say formally mathematical way?

Or if it is false, what is the solution? Please show me explanatorily. Thank you for help

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Draw a square with center $(x_0,y_0)$ and  side  $4r $  in a circle and show that its  radius is $\sqrt{2} r$.

Comment: But I found the question from partial derivatives exercises. This is geometrically answer. But how do I do with mathematically approcach? By the way thank you for help:)

Comment: I don't think that the answer is related to the partial derivatives since basically it's a topological question.

Comment: Hmm, I am studying from fitzpatrick's advanced calculus book. This question is from there.